# Variance - particular outcomes of $X$

Tags: probability, variance

If $x_i$ is a particular outcome of the random variable $X$, and $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution of $X$, then is it true that $E[(x_i-\mu)^2] = Var(X)$?

Maybe I should ask a different question: is it true that $E[x_i]=E[X]$? $x_i$ is already known to us - that's the source of my confusion. We cannot expect anything from something we know.

Comment: What do you mean by $x_i$ is known to us? Has it already taken place? What is the probability that $x=x_i$?

Answer (score 0):

It is common to write random variable as upper case letters and realizations as lowercase. Following this standard, and as you say, $x_i$ is a realization or outcome. $x_i$ is simply a number, not a random variable.

$E(x_i)=x_i$ which is only equal to $E(X)=\mu$ by coincidence.

Similarly, $E[(x_i-\mu)^2] = (x_i-\mu)^2$ this will only be equal to $Var(X)=\sigma^2$ by coincidence.